# Disable date before current date in JQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to disable the date before current date in date picker. How to do this?

```js
$(function() {
  var $dp1 = $("#datepicker1");
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $dp1.datepicker({
      changeYear: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
      yearRange: "-100:+20",
    });
  });
});

$(function() {
  var $dp2 = $("#datepicker2");
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $dp2.datepicker({
      changeYear: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      yearRange: "-100:+20",
      dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
    });
  });
});
```

```css
p.pfield-wrapper input {
  float: right;
}
p.pfield-wrapper::after {
  content: "\00a0\00a0 "; /* keeps spacing consistent */
  float: right;
}
p.required-field::after {
  content: "*";
  float: right;
  margin-left: -3%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p class="pfield-wrapper required-field">
  <label>Start Date</label>
  <input id="datepicker1" type="text" name="s" style="width:155px;" required value="">
</p>
<p class="p">End Date
  <input id="datepicker2" type="text" name="e" style="width:155px;" value="">
</p>
```

[Equivalent JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mount/zbabqyts/4/)

Comment: why you need to use more than one document.ready events ?

Comment: Added the fiddle link to the question, along with an equivalent StackSnippet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) property in JQuery UI datepicker API.

```
$(function() {
  var $dp1 = $("#datepicker1");
  $dp1.datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
      minDate:0,
    dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
    yearRange: "-100:+20",
  });

  var $dp2 = $("#datepicker2");
  $dp2.datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+20",
    dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var $dp1 = $("#datepicker1");
  $dp1.datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
    yearRange: "-100:+20",
  });

  var $dp2 = $("#datepicker2");
  $dp2.datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+20",
    dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
  });
});
```

```css
p.pfield-wrapper input {
  float: right;
}
p.pfield-wrapper::after {
  content: "\00a0\00a0 "; /* keeps spacing consistent */
  float: right;
}
p.required-field::after {
  content: "*";
  float: right;
  margin-left: -3%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p class="pfield-wrapper required-field">
  <label>Start Date</label>
  <input id="datepicker1" type="text" name="s" style="width:155px;" required value="">
</p>
<p class="p">End Date
  <input id="datepicker2" type="text" name="e" style="width:155px;" value="">
</p>
```

[Equivalent JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbabqyts/8/)

Also note that you need to use only one document ready event in your script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) option

```
    $dp1.datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
        yearRange: "-100:+20",
        minDate: '0'
    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zbabqyts/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Date').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

            var today = new Date();
            today = Date.parse(today.getMonth()+1+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear());

            var selDate = Date.parse(dateText);

            if(selDate < today) {

                $('#Date').val('');
                $(inst).datepicker('show');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="Date" value="" />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW7cs/184/)**

**NOTE:or use minDate: 0**

As per your example :

**Method1**

**html**

```
 <p class="pfield-wrapper required-field"> <label>Start Date</label>         <input id="datepicker1" type="text" name="s"  style="width:155px;" required value=""></p>
    <p class="p">End Date<input id="datepicker2" type="text" name="e"  style="width:155px;" value=""></p>
```

**JS**

```
      $(function () {
   var $dp1 = $("#datepicker1");
  $(document).ready(function () {

  $dp1.datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
        minDate: '0',
    dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
    yearRange: "-100:+20",
  });
 });

        });

          $(function () {
   var $dp2 = $("#datepicker2");


  $dp2.datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
       minDate: '0',
    yearRange: "-100:+20",
    dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",

 });

        });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zbabqyts/9/)**

**METHOD2**

**html**

```
 <p class="pfield-wrapper required-field"> <label>Start Date</label>         <input id="datepicker1" type="text" name="s"  style="width:155px;" required value=""></p>
    <p class="p">End Date<input id="datepicker2" type="text" name="e"  style="width:155px;" value=""></p>
```

**js**

```
 $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            //Get today's date at midnight
            var today = new Date();
            today = Date.parse(today.getMonth()+1+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear());
            //Get the selected date (also at midnight)
            var selDate = Date.parse(dateText);

            if(selDate < today) {
                //If the selected date was before today, continue to show the datepicker
                $('#datepicker1').val('');
                $(inst).datepicker('show');
            }
        }
    });



$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            //Get today's date at midnight
            var today = new Date();
            today = Date.parse(today.getMonth()+1+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear());
            //Get the selected date (also at midnight)
            var selDate = Date.parse(dateText);

            if(selDate < today) {
                //If the selected date was before today, continue to show the datepicker
                $('#datepicker2').val('');
                $(inst).datepicker('show');
            }
        }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW7cs/185/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this if you have start date and end date

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
     minDate: '0',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
    }
});
$("#txtToDate").datepicker({
     minDate: '0',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
       $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
    }
});  
});
```